# Powershell remoting - cannot execute an exe as another user

Tags: powershell, remoting

I've a commandline program (c#) that encrypts config files based on machine key.
A powershell script copies the build to a Target Server, modifies configs accordingly and installs windows services. 
All the windows services run as local system account (standard user, non-admin) - let's call this account "locuser".

The Target Server is a Win 2012 R2 Server. All of the above is achieved by PS remoting from the Build Server to this Target server.

Now, I need to run the encrypt commandline program as "locuser", so that the program can use the account specific key to do the encryption.
I know that this can be easily achieved by calling `Start-Process` cmdlet with `-Credentials` parameter. Well, here's the catch, the above works fine, if I remote in (RDP) to the Target Server and then run the `Start-Process .... -Credential $cred` from a Powershell Console.

However, I need this to be working while I remote-in (using my scripts) to the TargetServer whilst deploying. When I remote-in to the TargetServer I use credentials that has Admin privileges.

I've tried the following

1. I've granted "locuser" both "Full Control" and "Invoke (Execute)" permissions by using the `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI` command. I've run this command for both `Microsoft.Powershell` and `Microsoft.Powershell32` - Still get Access Denied
2. I've edited the "Local Security Policy"->"Local Policies"->"User Rights Assignment"->Impersonate a client after authentication - and added both the Admin account (that I login with) and the "locuser" account - Still get Access Denied
3. I've also granted locuser admin rights - Still get Access Denied

I'm pretty sure, there is some configuration on the PS Remoting Side of things that I'm missing out but can't figure out what - because all Powershell throws me is a `Access Denied` error (see screenshot) with little to no useful information to troubleshoot further.

Also, checked Event logs for any traces but to no avail.

[image: PS Remoting Error]

Answer (score 0):

You've fallen prey to the dreaded Double Hop. Basically you're authenticating from computer A to computer B, then trying to authenticate again from computer B to computer C (which also happens to be B in this case).

If at all possible, you would be better off ending the session and starting a new one with the locuser credentials, then just calling Start-Process. Another, more messy approach is to use schtasks.

I can tell you how to do it in the same session but it's a bit messy and very complicated, and should only be a last resort:

On the originating server (Build Server):

1. Run the command `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -Delegate [name]` where `[name]` is an IP or DNS address / range including any target servers (eg "192.168.1.*")
2. Open GPEdit.msc, navigate to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation` and check that the rules `Allow delegating fresh credentials` and `Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM...` are enabled and include `[name]`

On the Target Server:

1. Run the command `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server`

Running the command:

```
Invoke-Command [targetserver] [-Credential $cred] -Scriptblock {
    ## do stuff

    Invoke-Command . -Credential $locusercred -Authentication Credssp -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process -FilePath $sc #etc
    }
}
```

Some things to be aware of:

Firstly I used this setup to create a local session, then remote from there (so A-A-B instead of A-B-B) so the Group Policy stuff might be in the wrong place but pretty sure it's right.

Secondly I found that credentials are a pain to get working in sessions (in this case `$locusercred`). I did get it going natively but weirdly it suddenly couldn't decrypt the securestring. I ended up saving a securestring with a defined key to the registry so it can always be decrypted from any account, you may need to come up with your own solution there.

All this stuff is explained in the free eBook ["The Secrets of PowerShell Remoting"](https://www.gitbook.com/book/devopscollective/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/details), if you go for the double-hop approach I recommend giving it a read.

Comment: Actually I just realised I didn't explain why this is an issue. It's because you're sending credentials over to another computer and then on to a third computer from there and Windows doesn't entirely trust that it isn't being impersonated or redirected. Basically it's a security precaution so you have to add a bunch of exceptions for stuff you trust and enable it to confirm you know what you're doing.

Comment: I've tried the above command .. it now gives me a more detailed error -- [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the 
request. CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request 
again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the server configuration.

Comment: I ran this from both servers - I get the same error when I run it from both the Originating Server (Build Server) and the Target Server - I also enabled delegating credentials on the Target server too just to be sure.. still the same error :( - could it be that locuser should be configured with Enable-WSManCredSSP? Not sure how to do that though .. I cant even run Powershell console as admin, logged in as locuser

Comment: I did go through the "Remoting Secrets" books but what I'm not convinced is that the second call (Running command as locuser) can be considered a hop - Once you are logged in to TargetServer, as long as one has credentials to a local account on the same server, they should be able to Run any commands as that user (within their permission scope) - I'm thinking it has to do with locuser needing some permission/access - I shall continue my investigation ...

Comment: The error is saying the value of `WSMAN:\localhost\client\auth\credssp` is not `$true` - this needs to be set on both servers. I don't think it's different per user account. However it's definitely a double hop issue, try doing -anything- with credentials in a PSSession and it will fail, because it has to create a session for that user and it can't do that from a session.

Comment: sorry for the delay - yes, I have enabled CredSSP client auth on both the servers (build, target servers) but still no luck - I still get access denied. However, I found a workaround - I now invoke another session with locuser credentials from the originating server and get my job done. I wasn't able to ps-remote-in to locuser, until I added locuser to group "Remote Management Users" on the Target Server. It's not ideal but works for now.

Comment: That should have been the first thing you tried really but worked out in the end =)

Comment: @obfuscate, how did you 'invoke another session'? I have exactly the same issue as you originally described. If I `New-PSSession` while in a remote session, i get a new error _A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated._